# Scrollbar not functioning on Tkinter Figure Canvas

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, scrollbar, figure

I realize there are similar questions already posted, but I have attempted to follow each solution with no luck.

I have a figure created using matplotlib that has a variable amount of subplots. This figure is large and so many of the subplots are not visible on the page.

I'm trying to add a scrollbar to allow the user to view the additional subplots. The scrollbar appears just as I expected it to, but it does not function at all.

Below is a portion of the code for this page.

```
class PageTwo(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f,self)
        canvas.draw()

        scroll=Scrollbar(self, orient = VERTICAL)
        scroll.pack(side = RIGHT, fill=tk.BOTH)

        canvas.get_tk_widget().config(yscrollcommand=scroll.set)
        scroll.config(command=canvas.get_tk_widget().yview)

        canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP,fill=tk.BOTH,expand = True)
```

Here is the result:

[Figure Canvas with Scrollbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YIUuW.png)

Comment: Is there anything drawn on the canvas?

Comment: Is the scroll bar grayed out?

Comment: Yes, I used FigureCanvasTkAgg to act as the canvas so that I could easily add my figure to the window.

Yes, the scroll bar is grayed out and completely useless at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the scrollbar by configuring the scroll region using the following:

```
canvas.get_tk_widget().config(scrollregion=(0,0,1000,10000))
```

However, when I scroll now, the figure is cut off where the bottom of the page used to be (See Image):

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vq7pN.png)

I'm now trying to figure out how to extend the FigureCanvasTkAgg to be able to view all of the subplots.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. You probably didn't put scroolbar into canvas.

```
class PageTwo(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f,self)
        canvas.draw()

        scroll=Scrollbar(canvas, orient = VERTICAL)
        scroll.pack(side = RIGHT, fill=tk.BOTH)

        canvas.get_tk_widget().config(yscrollcommand=scroll.set)
        scroll.config(command=canvas.get_tk_widget().yview)

        canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP,fill=tk.BOTH,expand = True)
```

So I changed this.
`scroll=Scrollbar(self, orient = VERTICAL)`
To this `scroll=Scrollbar(canvas, orient = VERTICAL)`

Comment: I tried it, I got the error: AttributeError: 'FigureCanvasTkAgg' object has no attribute 'tk'

Comment: FigureCanvasTkAgg looking stranger. Can't you do it without canvas? Or are you'd like to use LabelFrame?

Comment: I used FigureCanvasTkAgg because i have that figure with all of my subplots on it that I would like to paste into a canvas with the scrollbar (you can see the issue in the image I posted).
From my understanding, you need to draw a canvas with the figure in order to display the figure.

Comment: try not to use (config() and .pack())s in 1 line. and sorry I dont know more about matplotlib.